# One-to-one property of a matrix with trivial null space

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be a $5 \times 4$ matrix with $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Nul}(A))=0$. Then the linear
>   transformation $T: \mathbb R^4 \rightarrow\mathbb R^5,\; T(X)=Ax$ is one-to-one.

Can anyone explain what the answer is?

Comment: Do you have any guess as to what the answer is?  Any thoughts on how to approach it?

Comment: If $A x = Ay$ then $A(x-y) = 0$. What does that say about $x-y$?

Comment: @copper.hat x-y=0 ?

Comment: Three words that come to my mind are Rank, Nullity, Theorem, and the first and third point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Properties)

Comment: What would $\dim \ker A = 0$ mean about $\ker A$?

Comment: @copper.hat Is it true? Because the linear transformation x -> Ax is one-to-one if and only if Nul A = 0?

Comment: Trust the facts and connect the dots :-).

Comment: @copper.hat thank you :)

Comment: @tk4982: you are welcome, Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean injective with "one to one", the answer is yes.

If it were not the case, there would be 
$\DeclareMathOperator{img}{img}y_1, y_2 \in \img T$ with 
$y_1 = T(x_1), y_2 = T(x_1)$, $x_1 \ne x_2$ but $y_1 = y_2$.

This however means $T(x_1 - x_2) = T(x_1) - T(x_2) = y_1 - y_2 = 0$ so
$x_1 - x_2 \in \ker T$.  As $x_1 \ne x_2$ it would mean $x_1 - x_2 \ne 0$,
so there would be a non-zero vector in the kernel of $T$. This is in contradiction to the property $\ker T = \{ 0 \}$, as $\dim \ker T$ was zero.

Comment: One to one usually means injective

Comment: This is confusing, the question was about injectivity.

Comment: @mvw So the answer is false?

Comment: @tk4982 Now it is true, because $T$ is injective. Before it was false, because $T$ is not bijective. :)